# Why json_encode doesn´t work in PHP 7.0, but it work in PHP 7.3?

Tags: php, json, session-variables

I have created a script and I have test it on PHP 7.3. But now I need to execute it on PHP 7.0, but json_encode is not working

```
<script>
<?php
$js_array = json_encode($_SESSION[CUSTOMER_NAMES]);
echo "var customerNames = " . $js_array . ";\n";
?>
            var customer = document.getElementById("customer");
            var uploadLogo = document.getElementById("uploadLogo");

            customer.addEventListener("input", function(){
            var found = customerNames.find(element => element == customer.value);
            if(found == undefined){
            uploadLogo.style.display = "block";
            }else{
            uploadLogo.style.display = "none";
            }
            });
        </script>
```

So, when I run it in PHP7.0 customerNames is empty, but if I run it on PHP 7.3 it takes the values of $_SESSION[CUSTOMER_NAMES], that it´s an array of strings

Return with PHP 7.3:

> var customerNames = [["Acail"],["Acciona Energia"]];

Return with PHP 7.0:

> var customerNames = ;

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) What type is `$_SESSION[CUSTOMER_NAMES]`? (Both in PHP 7.0 and in PHP 7.3; my guess is 7.0 has some kind of nullish value, and 7.3 doesn't.) Also, please quote (copy and paste) the output you see in PHP 7.0 ("empty" can mean many things) and the output you see in PHP 7.3.

Comment: It seems very unlikely this has anything to do with JSON or `json_encode`. It's going to be `$_SESSION[CUSTOMER_NAMES]`.

Comment: I use that session variable in another part of the code and it has values, that´s not the problem. I haven´t put all the code here because it has 1000 lines, but the session variable has values

Comment: CUSTOMER_NAMES does look suspicious I agree. Shouldn't it be in quote marks? [json_last_error_msg()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php) can tell you if something went wrong with the JSON encoding process, though.

Comment: I´m going to try using json_last_error_msg() , but it´s going to take some time, because I´m running that on a server and I have to change it there

Comment: Also make sure you've got PHP set to log errors and warnings to a file, in case there is another unseen problem.

Comment: @ADyson How do I set PHP to log errors and warnings to a file?

Comment: ....it's not hard to google it! But here's a decent guide: https://stackify.com/php-error-logs-guide/

Comment: `json_encode();` can get a bit flaky with non ASCII or latin1 characters, so if you have any other encoding, that could cause issues. You could try `json_encode( $_SESSION[CUSTOMER_NAMES], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @BenHillier I have tried that and it isn´t the solution